# Migrate apps from Ubuntu to Fedora

Tags: migration

Hi
I have Ubuntu on my machine with several apps installed and lots of configurations made, but I want to test fedora 15 (when it comes). the problem is that I dont want (and cant) install same apps on fedora using internet (main problem is bandwidth), and also i dont have the time to make the same configurations to fedora. is there any way to migrate apps to fedora + conf files?
thanx in advance ;-)

Comment: This kind of question goes on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: The question is related to Ubuntu and it is a "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". So it's completely fine to ask it here.

Comment: Come on @Jorge, just taking a look at fedora doesn't mean that you should become angry! kiddin' ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To migrate the configuration files you just have to migrate your home folder, it includes all the user specific application configurations, and since both Ubuntu and Fedora use Gnome per default this should work rather well.

Migrating the installed applications without reinstalling them from Fedora is a profoundly bad idea. Time and effort needed left aside, it will likely result in a very suboptimal, unstable system. Just don't do it, reinstall the apps from Fedora.

(Reasons start with different file system trees and configuration methods between distributions, and probably won't stop with differing file and library versions within individual software packages.)

Answer (score 0):

Not going to happen. You can easily copy over configs without issue but even if you did retain EVERY deb file you ever downloaded (doubtful) then I am not sure they would work. I suggest you post on a Fedora forum as Fedora is not supported here.